# How to give some specific symbols to python translate function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string that contains:
`" ' : ;`
i am using `.translate(None," "':; ")`
But this isnt working as `""` is facing ambiguity in opening and closing commas.
Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the quote:

```
foo.translate(None," \"':; ")
```

Comment: Thanks for help! I am sure I am going to face "/" & "\" in my string in future. Any Suggestions??

Comment: If you need a backslash in there, then escape that as well: ```\\```.